# Lifting Ratio between different parts of your body

Tags: weightlifting, training, upper-body-workout, programs

I want to avoid overtraining certain part of my body with respect to other parts, I'd like to maintain a certain equilibrium in my body. What I want is basically a ratio of the weights i should lift with different part of the body. To do a simplistic example with random number: if you do 10 reps at 10 (some weight unit) at the bench press you should be able to do 10 reps at the lat machine at 9. I'm not sure if I've been clear enough. I know there isn't a perfect ratio but there must be something to be around, more or less. If your bodyweight 70 Kg, you bench press 100 kg but you can't do more than 2 pull ups it means you're doing something wrong.

Thank you in advance for any answer and i hope i made myself clear

Comment: We all are different. You can have stronger legs, or upper part of body, back... As I understand that is the question. How to train to deal with it? If so, I would propose other sport - like judo, wrestling. That way you will use all the body in more natural way. Gym, weight-lifting can support that, but should not be your main routine.

Comment: I agree with you, but for a couple of months gym is the only thing I can do

Comment: In that case don't concentrate on maximal power. Rather think about stability. Maybe explosive power, but more in terms of whole body. Problem with explosive power is that you need proper technique, and that comes with time...

Answer (score 2):

There's no perfect way as such ratio.

First of all, you have a misunderstanding of overtraining. That is a complex syndrome, not some simple thing that you get from doing too many bicep curls.

Just periodize your volume and intensity and you should be good to go.

Comment: I said i knew there was no perfect ratio, but there must be something to be around in order to reach some kind of equilibrium. I didn't talk about overtraining syndrome in a technical way, I just meant overtrain a certain part of the body too much with respect to other parts. To paraphrase, working out too much on something and not doing enough of something else. I don't think doing it randomly would help

Comment: Take in account that what youre asking is basically a correct prediction of how much a muscle will grow at given amount of work. This is impossible to know in precise terms

Comment: I'm not talking a balance in muscle growth or aesthetic harmony. I'm talking about some kind of internal balance and harmony in the body. I just don't think it's healthy to bench press 150 kg and be able to do 3 pullups at 70 kg of bodyweight even if i have both chest and muscles developed and and in balance in terms of how big they are and how they look. I know there isn't a perfect ratio, in fact I just asked for some raw guidelines, some "more or less". I've always played football and never do weights in my life and I don't wanna start doing them randomly without good balance.

Answer (score 1):

While maintaining a balance is good, some muscles can't withstand the load some others can. Lats is a pulling exercise, while bench is pushing. I know people who bench 500 lbs, but haven't seen them pulling 500 lbs on lat machine, though i don't observe people much in general. Also, you can always squat heavier than what you can lift overhead.

The main goal should be to exercise the full body and try to strengthen the weaker areas. How much weight you are lifting for which one, is immaterial, as long as you are doing it with proper form, and getting better than before.

Comment: Yeah that's what i meant, every muscle has to be trained differently, but the body is one and it has to have an equilibrium. Working out just the upper body is not a good training and doesn't guarantee you a balance in your body. Since I can't lift the same with every part of my body I'm asking what should be more or less the ratio in order to not neglet some muscles and giving too much importance to others